# работа с файлами, создание множества файлов

Tags: c++

у меня есть буфер определенного размера, нужно сделать так, чтобы когда буфер заполнялся, то его содержимое скидывалось в файл, но у файла тоже есть размер, и когда он заполняется, должен создаваться новый файл, и запись должна идти в него, предположим, в буфер можно поместить 3 символа, а файл рассчитан на 5, я записываю 3 символа в буфер, он кидает их в файл, я записываю еще два символа в буфер и программа создает новый файл, потому что в нем уже 5 символов, я записываю последний 3-й символ в буфер, и он должен скинуть его в новый файл

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef std::string  NewString;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 3; 
int MAX_SIZE;

void  make_file(const NewString&  file_name);

int main()
{
    const NewString BASE_FILE_NAME = "file";
    const NewString FILENAME_EXTENSION = "txt";
    NewString newFileName = BASE_FILE_NAME + '_' + '0' + '.' + FILENAME_EXTENSION;

    fstream file;
    file.open(newFileName, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

    vector<string> buffer;
    string value;
    int counter = 0;
    int file_counter = 0;

    cout << "enter MAX_SIZE: ";
    cin >> MAX_SIZE;
    cout << "enter the buffer" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        buffer.push_back(value);

        counter++;
        file_counter++;
        if (counter == BUFFER_SIZE)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<buffer.size();k++)
                file << buffer[k];
            file.close();
            counter = 0;
            buffer.clear();
        }

        if (file_counter == 5)
        {
            std::ostringstream  sout;
            sout << i;
            newFileName = BASE_FILE_NAME + '_' + sout.str() + '.' + FILENAME_EXTENSION;
            file.open(newFileName, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
            make_file(BASE_FILE_NAME + '_' + sout.str() + '.' + FILENAME_EXTENSION);
            file_counter = 0;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void  make_file(const NewString&  file_name)
{
    std::ofstream  ofile(file_name.c_str());
}
```

файлы- то у меня новые создаются,только вместо 5 символов в них пишется только 3 символа, а в последний файл не записывается ничего, данные не полностью записываются в файл, например, я ввожу

```
q w e r t y u i o p
```

в 1-й файл запишется q w e, вместо q w e r t, во 2-й запишется r t y, вместо y u i o p , я не знаю почему и как это исправить

Comment: Раз вы используете stdlib и с++, начните рефакторинг с написания класса.

Так же у вас довольно скверно написан код работы с файлами.

Есть объект file, который можно закрывать и тем самым выгружать буффер записанных данных из ОЗУ в файл на диске, а после этого переоткрывать объект для обработки нового файла. 

make_file функция в данном коде некорректна.

Comment: почему make_file не корректна?

Comment: почему make_file не корректна?.. Потому что в функции вы создаете  файловый обьект  для записи и после выхода из функции вы его теряете даже не закрывая файл